# Saving data to Google SQL (via JDBC) from AdWords Scripts is very slow

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote an AdWords script to save the performance data to Google Cloud via JDBC.
Unfortunately, the script exceeds the 30 minutes maximum runtime and saves only around 20% of the data. Is there a way to speed this up and finish the process for all the products within the 30minutes runtime limit?

Please, see below the main part of the code.
The first paragraph fetches the desired data for each product ID.
I believe this part is ok.
The second paragraph writes a row for every product ID.
And here, probably, is the problem as it has to establish the connection each time for every product and it takes ages.

```
  while (productGroups.hasNext()) {    
    var productGroup = productGroups.next();
    var productItemId = productGroup.asItemId();
    var maxCpc = productItemId.getMaxCpc();
    var itemId = productItemId.getValue();
    var stats = productItemId.getStatsFor('YESTERDAY');
    var averageCpc = stats.getAverageCpc();
    var clicks = stats.getClicks();
    var impressions = stats.getImpressions();
    var conversions = stats.getConversions();
    var cost = stats.getCost();


    if (itemId || maxCpc) {   
 var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd); //SQL Connetion starts here
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO table1 '
      + '(itemid, date, clicks, impressions, cpc, averageCpc, cost, conversions) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'); //End 
  stmt.setString(1, itemId);
  stmt.setString(2, now);
  stmt.setString(3, clicks);
  stmt.setString(4, impressions);
  stmt.setString(5, maxCpc);
  stmt.setString(6, averageCpc);
  stmt.setString(7, cost);
  stmt.setString(8, conversions);    
  stmt.execute();
    }    
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The simple solution is to not define the connection in the loop. If you know that is bad and inefficient, why do you still do it? Just do it first, before you loop. Also I'm sure there is a way to send more than one statement at a time, e.g. "Batch insert"

Comment: It worked! I put the first line of the connection outside the loop and script has finished in 13 minutes. I can believe it was so simple! Thank you